# Getting certain Text only

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I am working with google map api ,

I am providing longitude and latitude from front end , what i need to assert is that , map showing specify longitude and latitude .

Here is text from src =http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=22.396428,114.109497&markers=22.396428,114.109497&zoom=18&size=544x362&sensor=false

I wanted to assert '22.396428,114.109497' text contain in url specified , 
I do I attain this .

Thanks

Comment: please either accept the answer or clarify why the answer does not help you solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This an example of how you'd do that with Hamcrest.

```
MatcherAssert.assertThat(driver.getCurrentUrl(),
                         Matchers.containsString("22.396428,114.109497"));
```